# Как из файла достать строки и преобразовать в массив для использования в программе

Tags: python-3.x, файлы

Преобразовать его в [(1,2,7),(1,3.6),(1,4,7)] для дальнейшей обработки

[image: Файл выглядит вот так]

```
R = [(1, 2, 13), (1, 3, 18), (1, 4, 17), (1, 5, 14)]
```

что бы весь файл просто записать в R, как в примере

Comment: У вас были попытки написать это самостоятельно? Код в студию

Comment: Я сначала думал нужно просто поменять ему формат и всё заработает, потом когда понял что это глупо, попробовал хотя би в числовом формате вывести, это получилось, но я не знаю как корректно разделить его на отдельные [(), ()], так что особо нечего показывать :) "\n" Возможно нужно изначально сделать R = [], а потом после как-то сделать ограничение после 3 чисел

Answer (score 0):

```
R = []
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for i in f.readlines():
        R.append(i.split(' '))
print(R)
```

Comment: Потом его ещё нужно в числовой формат поменять? И вопрос (1, 1 ,1) == [1, 1, 1]?

Comment: "И вопрос (1, 1 ,1) == [1, 1, 1]?" А самому проверить слабо? False

Answer (score 0):

```
txt ='1 2 3\n' \
     '4 5 7\n' \
     '8 9 0\n'

print([tuple(map(int, x.split())) for x in txt.splitlines()])

[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 7), (8, 9, 0)]
```